# Definition of a bounded linear functional - why not $|T(f)|\leq M$ instead of $|T(f)|\leq M||f||$

Tags: real-analysis, definition

In Royden's *Real Analysis* there's the following definition:

[image]

Why is this the definition of a bounded linear functional? Why is it not $|T(f)|\leq M$?(I'm trying to understand the intuition behind this definition rather than just taking it at face value).

There's what seems like a relevant direction for a response [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407323/question-about-definition-of-bounded-linear-functionals) (the first one, by Andreas Blas), but it doesn't exactly answer my question (at least from my understanding).

Comment: remember these are linear maps, they won't be bounded in the traditional sense unless very boring

Comment: @operatorerror Do you have examples? Ideally one for a boring class and one for a non-boring class so I can better understand what you mean?

Comment: The **only** bounded linear map, in the usual sense of bounded function, is the null map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that there exists $M$ such that that for each $f$ we have $|T(f)| \le M$. For any $a>0$, it follows that
$$a|T(f)| = |T(af)| \le M \implies |T(f)| \le \frac{M}{a}
$$
Letting $a \to 0$, it follows that $|T(f)|=0$. So $T$ is the zero functional.

The intuition I like to think about for boundedness of a linear functional goes something like this. We know (by the argument above) that for any linear functional $T$ on $X$ and any $f \ne 0 \in X$, when $|T(af)|$ is evaluated as $a \ge 0$ varies, the result is either a constant equal to zero or it increases to infinity linearly as $a$ increases. But on that ray $\{af \mid a \ge 0\}$ there is one very special, unique point, namely the point where the ray pierces through the unit sphere of the norm: that's the point $\frac{f}{\|f\|}$. So to say that $T$ is a bounded linear functional means that if we restrict $f$ so that it varies just over the unit sphere $\|f\|=1$, the values of $|Tf|$ are bounded. This is exactly equivalent to requiring that the values of $\frac{|Tf|}{\|f\|}$ are bounded, as $f$ varies over all nonzero elements of $X$.